# Symfony2: Page Event Listener

Tags: php, symfony

I need to implement an event listener to verify that the user has privileges to access a client's project.

My routes look like this:

```
/client_a/dashboard/
/client_b/dashboard/
```

A user may only have privileges to access "Client A", so I need to verify and redirect the user, if he/she is not allowed to see that project.

Is the page event listener the best approach? If so, what event would I be listening to?

Alternatively, if there is a better way of handling the scenario, what would that look like?

Thanks,

JB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a *much* better way to do this using the native ACL functionality provided by Symfony2.
[This "book" entry will explain it pretty clearly.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input, David. I've looked at the ACL functionality early on, but I'm not clear as to the implementation for the above scenario. Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Apply ACL permissions as fit (read-only, read-write [or a more simplistic model]) to each client (I'm assuming each client has a class). Then, instead of setting up an entire service, on your client_x route, you can just access the security context to check for permissions like this: `if( $securityContext->isGranted('READ', $clientObject) )`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/client_X/dashboard/` isn't the *only* route you want to secure, you could listen for the `kernel.request` [event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-request-event).

Your listener would probably need the security context service injected into it, so you could access the user's info. Then you'd simply check if the user has access to a certain client and react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Arms, that confirms what I had in mind, but wanted to make sure it's the best approach. I already have the security context in place for both authentication and authorization, so we should be good there. 

Thanks for jumping in and giving feedback!